# Salvar mais de um registro PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para dar um update em mais de um registro, por exemplo aparece na pagina notas.php as seguintes informações:

[image: Print da tela com as informações]

Estas informações são de um banco, portanto são ids diferente cada aluno.
O meu problema é quando clicar no botão salvar, pois quando clico ele só salva o ultimo item. O que posso fazer neste caso?

**Codigo utilizado**

```
<form method="GET" action="notas.php">
<input type='text' placeholder='Nota' name='nota' id='nota' value=" .$linha['nota_valori'] . ">
<button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

No notas.php tem:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$nota = $_POST['nota'];
$sql="UPDATE `nota` SET nota_valori='$nota' WHERE nota_id=$id";
$executa= mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Registro salvo com sucesso";
```

Comment: Pode postar o código? Fica mais fácil para ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o código html e php

Comment: O codigo está em cima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve transformar seus campos do formulário em um `array` e armazenar o id em um campo `hidden`. por exemplo:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='<?php echo $id ?>'>
<input type='text' name='nota[]' value='<?php echo $nota?>'>
```

E no php do form quando você receber os dados, basta percorrer com um `foreach` e tratar os dados da maneira que necessita.

```
<?php

$data = isset($_POST) ? $_POST : [];

foreach($data['id'] as $key => $value){

        $id = $value;
        $nota = $data['nota'][$key];

        $sql="UPDATE `nota` SET nota_valori='$nota' WHERE nota_id=$id";
        $executa= mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

}

echo "Registro salvo com sucesso";
?>
```

São apenas dados de exemplos para você ter uma idéia do que fazer.

Comment: Tentei usar isto mas está aparecendo o seguinte erro
**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\escola\admin\update.php on line 162**

Comment: Você está usando mysql do php e não pdo, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: @DanielAlencarSouza, de nada!